Cannot install corss-spawn 7.0.5 with npm
Using node version: v16.20.1
Trying to override cross-spawn to version 7.0.5 which is latest.
My package.json looks something like this.
{
"overrides": {
  "cross-spawn": "7.0.5"
 }
}

When I run this command npm i. I get this error.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for cross-spawn@7.0.5.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

I have checked that 7.0.5 exists with
npm show cross-spawn versions
Version Logs
[
  '0.1.0', '0.1.1', '0.1.2', '0.1.3', '0.1.4',
  '0.1.5', '0.1.6', '0.1.7', '0.2.0', '0.2.1',
  '0.2.2', '0.2.3', '0.2.4', '0.2.5', '0.2.6',
  '0.2.7', '0.2.8', '0.2.9', '0.3.0', '0.4.0',
  '0.4.1', '1.0.0', '1.0.1', '1.0.2', '1.0.3',
  '1.0.4', '2.0.0', '2.0.1', '2.1.0', '2.1.1',
  '2.1.2', '2.1.3', '2.1.4', '2.1.5', '2.2.0',
  '2.2.2', '2.2.3', '3.0.0', '3.0.1', '4.0.0',
  '4.0.2', '5.0.0', '5.0.1', '5.1.0', '6.0.0',
  '6.0.1', '6.0.2', '6.0.3', '6.0.4', '6.0.5',
  '7.0.0', '7.0.1', '7.0.2', '7.0.3', '7.0.4',
  '7.0.5'
]

Note: I am trying to update the transitive dependency. This package is not being used as direct dependency.
Can someone help on this?

I had this issue, was able to get the package info through npm view cross-spawn@^7.0.5 too
you can try cleaning your npm cache first and install again with
npm cache clean --force

